# What's the difference between 'pelican ./content' and 'make html'?

Tags: pelican

I start studying Pelican today because I want to move my blog from wordpress to pelican.

However, after reading the [docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.2/getting_started.html), I still don't know the difference between `pelican ./content` and `make html`. They both seem to generate a static website. Besides, `pelican ./content` always returns a `UnicodeDecodeError** for me, while`pelican ./content` does not.

What's the difference between them and why?

Answer (score 3):

In the folder where you use `$ pelican-quickstart`, you will find a file named **`Makefile`**.

You will find a line like this `html: clean $(OUTPUTDIR)/index.html`, and `$(OUTPUTDIR)/%.html:
    $(PELICAN) $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(CONFFILE) $(PELICANOPTS)`.

This file show you what pelican have done when you type `make ***`, and you can config many other things in this file.

Answer (score 2):

`pelican ./content` runs the generation of the website using defaults and trying to guess the location of your content, output and configuration files.

`make html` calls `pelican`, but explicitly gives it the input directory, the output directory, the configuration file and, optionally, some extra options.

Basically, `make html` (along with `make regenerate`) are convenience methods that make the job a bit easier for you. In any case, you should run `make publish` to generate the content that is to be uploaded to your web server, as it loads the `publishconf.py` files, which define a few extra options (the rss feeds) and allows you to change settings for the "proper" website.